# Project connection to CVS lost on reboot

Tags: aptana

In Aptana Studio 1.5.1, if Aptana is open when a reboot occurs, when I reopen Aptana, some project folders get changed from the folder+orange cylinder icon to just the folder icon, meaning that the projects are no longer connected to CVS. If I re-checkout the projects, all of the files I've edited but didn't commit are overwritten with the repository copy. I can save a copy of my edited files, re-checkout the project, and then copy my edited files back over, but then Aptana tells me each file is out-of-synch with the repository, and I have to fix that file-by-file. Is there an easy way to reattach a project on my local hard drive to the existing project in the repository and have it go back to the state it was in before the reboot messed up the workspace info?

Answer (score 1):

After a couple of days' research, I can now answer my own question. The easiest way I have found to restore the link to CVS when it has been lost (i.e. the orange "disk" icon no longer appears over the project folder) due to a reboot with Aptana open or some other catastrophe seems to be the following:

- In your local file system, make a backup copy of the project folder you want to reconnect as it exists, with all your uncommitted changes.
- In the Aptana perspective, right click on the folder and choose Delete.
- At the Delete Resources window, select the check box to "Delete project contents on disk", but only AFTER you have made the backup mentioned above.
- After the project folder is deleted, go to the CVS Repository Exploring perspective and click the Checkout from CVS button in the main Aptana toolbar.
- Choose "Use existing repository location", select the repository, and click Next.
- Choose "Use an existing module", select the module, and click Next.
- Choose "Check out as a project in the workspace", make sure the project folder name is in the "Project Name" box, choose "Checkout subfolders" if needed, and click Finish.
- Switch to the Aptana perspective to view the project folder.
- Right-click the folder and choose Import.
- At the Select window, select File System and click Next.
- At the File system window, browse to the backup folder you want to import from. You must have the entire path to this folder in the From directory field; otherwise, Aptana will create subfolders that you don't want. So, for example, if the project folder you are reconnecting is named "common", the From directory should have something like "c:\xampp\htdocs\common" in it.
- Select the check box next to the folder displayed in the window below From directory to specify that you want to import all files in the folder.
- Select the "Overwrite existing resources without warning" check box.
- Leave "Create selected folders only" selected.
- Click Finish and wait while the files are copied over.
- Switch to the Team Synchronizing perspective and open the folder you just imported. Every file will show up as needing to be synchronized.
- Click the Synchronize button in the toolbar. Aptana will compare the files now in your folder with those in CVS and will remove from the list any files that have not been modified since they were last committed.
- You're back to where you were before the connection to CVS was lost.

Newer versions of Aptana may require somewhat different steps. I hope this is helpful to someone, sometime.